# Querying Oracle DB using query parameters Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

We are currently having a view in the Oracle DB. We need to create a Web API that accepts the input parameters and queries the view in the Oracle DB and returns the response in the JSON format. I am new to ASP.NET and the web services. Below is the code for the service

```
namespace TGSSample.Controllers
{
public class TGSSampDataController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string id)
    {

        List<OracleParameter> prms = new List<OracleParameter>();
        List<string> selectionStrings = new List<string>();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TGSDataConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection dbconn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
        {
            DataSet userDataset = new DataSet();
            var strQuery = "SELECT * from LIMS_SAMPLE_RESULTS_VW where JRS_NO =" + id;

            var returnObject = new { data = new OracleDataTableJsonResponses(connStr, strQuery, prms.ToArray()) };
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
            ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
            if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=ProvantisStudyData.json", out contentDisposition))
            {
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
            }
            return response;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to debug and in the URL I gave like http://localhost:6897/api/TGSSampData?id=379 but it throws error like enter image description here
[image]
I havent changed anything with the RouteConfig.cs or WebApiConfig.cs.

```
namespace TGSSample
{
 public static class WebApiConfig
 {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );        }}}
```

I am not sure why I am getting the error. I have changed anything or not renamed.Can anyone please help me with this
[image]

Comment: Your error message says you tried `/api/TGSData` not `/api/TGSSampData` - could that be the issue?

Comment: show webapiconfig

Comment: No controller is found on your path /api/TGSData, this is what the error saying to you. Also you have an error in building of your query. Your id should be in '', but better use OracleCommandParameters !

Comment: @Beno My apologies. I tried changing the application and missed updating the screenshot. I have updated the question

Comment: @Nkosi I have updated my question with the WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Don't you need `Getdetails` in your URI somewhere? That's the method you're calling

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, thing is that according to the mapped route it does not take the action name into account. but rather the http verb (GET)

Comment: I have the similar other application and it is being working without any issues. I am not sure what I am missing here

Comment: Have you registered the web api in the global.asax application start method? WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

> **Using [FromUri]**
>
> To force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the
>   **[FromUri]** attribute to the parameter.

Remove the **[FromUri]** attribute and you can use the **[HttpGet]** attribute as well.

```
public class TGSSampDataController : ApiController {
    //according to convention-based route mapping in webapiconfig
    //api/{controller}/{id} should map the following to this action
    //GET api/TGSSampData?id=379 
    //GET api/TGSSampData/379 
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id) { ... }
}
```

Comment: NKosi I made the change but still getting the same error. I tried giving as `api/TGSSampData?id=379` and also `api/TGSSampData/379`

Comment: Are there any other actions in the controller that was not included in the example?

Comment: No this is the only one, I have other classes for dealing with the JSON

Comment: How do we verify that. When I start the debugger  `http://localhost:24649/` the Home page comes up.

Comment: try calling an api controller via the default route in the browser or using postman or fiddler.

Comment: I just ran a simple integration test using the above controller and both urls suggestion and it hit the action both times.

Comment: I tried to test with the Fiddler. It is again throwing the same error I posted in the question again the screenshot. Will it be because any issue with the config

Comment: The exception message shows that it is hitting the mvc pipeline before even checking web api. are you sure you configured the web api properly? show where you call `WebApiConfig.Register`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128223/discussion-between-trx-and-nkosi).